# ValueError: shapes (7998,18) and (1498,18) not aligned: 18 (dim 1) != 1498 (dim 0)

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, logistic-regression

I have split my data frame into 80-5-15 for data training, and I also run an Ordinal Logistic regression for it. The training data and OLR are all good, but the accuracy test failed. My code is:

```
X_train_val_a1, X_test_a1, y_train_val_a1, y_test_a1 = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.15, random_state=42)
X_train_a1, X_val_a1, y_train_a1, y_val_a1 = train_test_split(X_train_val_a1, y_train_val_a1, test_size=0.059, random_state=42)
```

```
model_a1 = OrderedModel(y_train_a1, X_train_a1, distr='logit')  # Use X_train directly
result = model_a1.fit()print(result.summary())
```

```
pred_a1 = model_a1.predict(X_test_a1)prediction_a1 = list(map(round, pred_a1))print('\nTest accuracy = ', accuracy_score(y_test_a1, prediction_a1))
```

The error appears on

```
 pred_a1 = model_a1.predict(X_test_a1)
```

And the error message is:

```
ValueError: shapes (7998,18) and (1498,18) not aligned: 18 (dim 1) != 1498 (dim 0)
```

How can I tackle this problem?